# How to grep the string with specific pattern

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I am trying to grep a file.txt to search 2 strings cp and (target file name) where the line in file is as below,

```
cp (source file name) (target file name)
```

the problem for me here is string '(target file name)' has specific pattern as /path/to/file/TC_12_IT_(6 digits)_(6 digits)_*TC_12_TEST* _(2 digits).tc12.tc12

I am using below grep command to search a line with these 2 strings,

```
grep -E cp.*/path/to/file/TC_12_IT_ file.txt
```

how can I be more specific about (target file name) in grep command to search (target file name) with all its patterns, something like below,

```
grep -E 'cp.*/path/to/file/TC_12_IT_*_*_TC_12_TEST_*.tc12.tc12' file.txt
```

can we use wildcards in grep to search string in file just like we can use wilecard like * in listing out files e.g.

```
ls -lrt TC_12_*_12345678.txt
```

please suggest if there are any other ways to achieve this.

Comment: I have edited your post. Next time please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

More specifically:

```
grep -P '^cp\s+.+\s+\S+/TC_12_IT_\d{6}_\d{6}_TC_12_TEST _\d2[.]tc12[.]tc12$' in_file > out_file
```

`^` : beginning of the line.
`\s+` : 1 or more whitespace characters.
`.+` : 1 or more any characters.
`\S+` : 1 or more non-whitespace characters.
`\d{6}` : exactly 6 digits.
`[.]` : literal dot (`.`). Note that just plain `.` inside a regular expression means **any character**, unless it is inside a character class (`[.]`) or escaped (`\.`).
`$` : end of the line.

**SEE ALSO:**
[GNU `grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Answer (score 0):

Like this, using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -P 'cp.*TC_12_IT_\d{6}_\d{6}TC_12_TEST\d{2}.tc12.tc12' file
```

### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `cp` | 'cp' |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `TC_12_IT_` | 'TC_12_IT_' |
| `\d{6}` | digits (0-9) (6 times) |
| `_` | _ |
| `\d{6}` | digits (0-9) (6 times) |
| `TC_12_TEST` | 'TC_12_TEST' |
| `\d{2}` | digits (0-9) (2 times) |
| `.` | any character except \n |
| `tc12` | 'tc12' |
| `.` | any character except \n |
| `tc12` | 'tc12' |

Comment: did you mean   grep -P 'cp.*TC_12_IT_\d{6}_\d{6}TC_12_TEST\d{2}.tc12.tc12' file